# Python matrix manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the matrix (numpy) operations in Python and came across an interesting observation.

If I have the following code:

```
 x=matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
 y=matrix([[1.1,2.1],[3.1,4.1]])
 x=y
 print x
```

then it prints `[[1.1,2.1],[3.1,4.1]]`

However instead if I do

```
 x=matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
 y=matrix([[1.1,2.1],[3.1,4.1]])
 x[:,:]=y[:,:]
 print x
```

then it prints only the integer part i.e `[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Can someone tell me the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names `x` and `y` are just labels you can asisgn to objects.  They are not really "variables" as in other languages, and they don't have any type assigned to them.

Executing the line

```
x = y
```

will simply attach the label `x` to the object `y` is currently pointing to, and drop the reference to the object it was pointing to previously (possibly causing the old object to be garbage collected, if this was the only reference).  After executing this line, `x is y` returns `True`, indicating that they both point to the same object now.

The line

```
x[:] = y
```

on the other hand does not simply attach a new label to an object, but rather modifies an existing one, the one pointed to by `x`.  Since this existing object has the item type `int32`, all values need to be converted to integers.   After executing this line, `x is y` returns `False`, indicating that they point to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

your x matrix has a dtype of int32

Edit:
A more interesting result is this:

```py
>>> x = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]],dtype='f')
>>> y = np.matrix([[1.1,2.1],[3.1,4.1]],dtype='f')
>>> x[:,:] = y[:,:]
>>> x
matrix([[ 1.10000002,  2.0999999 ],
        [ 3.0999999 ,  4.0999999 ]], dtype=float32)
```

But this is caused by the python float error.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, when you use the assignment `x = y`, you are setting the memory location of `x` to the memory location of `y`, so basically `x` is now just a redundant variable pointing to the same location in memory that `y` points to. In that way, it looks like you are creating a copy of your matrix `y`, but in fact you are not. If you were to operate on `y` after this assignment and then `print x` and `print y`, you would see both of them change.

In the second case, because `x` is initialized as an integer matrix some automatic type casting is being applied to force the newly assigned values of each element of `x` to be integers. You are actually copying the values of your `y` matrix when you use the `x[:,:] = y[:,:]` assignment, but because `x` is an integer matrix, Python is basically executing `x[:,:] = int(y[:,:])`.

You could instead initialize `x` as:

```py
x = matrix([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
```

or as:

```py
x = matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype='f')
```

and you should see the result you are expecting after executing `x[:,:] = y[:,:]`.